# Insert data based on another cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I know a little bit about VBA but I can't seem to be able to work my way around this programming question.

I have a sheet where I want to program how many days it will take before the end of the tasking. Each Status are equal to a number of days, for exemple if a file is at the Pending stage it will take 180 total to be completed. But what i want is at each stage to write the number of days it will take. For example

Status is written in range E3:E160

If cell in range= Pending then
 Offset 4 columns over and write 20,  and offset 5 columns over and write 35 and offset 6 columns over and write 50, and offset 7 columns over and write 25, and offaet 8 columns over and write 15 and offset 9 columns over and write 15 and finally, offset 10 columns over and write 20

However if cell in range = "Planning" then offset 5 columns over and write 35, and offset 6 columns over and write 50 and so on until offset 10 columns over and write 20

The goal is tha for each status, the number of offset is based on the status.

Hope this help
I'm assuming ther will be a loop or something but I really can't figure it out.

Also it needs to be able to capture any new rows inserted within the range or outside the range.

Thanks to anyone who will be able to help me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
LastRow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow

    If Range("E" & i).Value = "Pending" Then

    Range("I" & i).Value = "20" And Range("J" & i).Value = 35 And Range("K" & i).Value = 50 And Range("L" & i).Value = 25 And Range("M" & i).Value = 15 And Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Planning" Then
    Range("J" & i).Value = 35 And Range("K" & i).Value = 50 And Range("L" & i).Value = 25 And Range("M" & i).Value = 15 And Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Screening" Then
    Range("K" & i).Value = 50 And Range("L" & i).Value = 25 And Range("M" & i).Value = 15 And Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Exam" Then
    Range("L" & i).Value = 25 And Range("M" & i).Value = 15 And Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Interview" Then
    Range("M" & i).Value = 15 And Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "References" Then
    Range("N" & i).Value = 15 And Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Closing" Then
    Range("O" & i).Value = 20

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Stack is not a code for me service. If you provide your code that you have written to this point with a specific issue we can troubleshoot but you aren't going to get a bespoke solution written from scratch.

Comment: Of course sorry, here's what I have so far, the problem with what I wrote is that it "works" but the only thing it does is that it writes 0 in the first range for each status. Hope you can help :-)

Comment: I have adred the code in my question

Answer (score 1):

```
If Range("E" & i).Value = "Pending" Then

    Range("I" & i).Value = 20
    Range("J" & i).Value = 35
    Range("K" & i).Value = 50
    Range("L" & i).Value = 25
    Range("M" & i).Value = 15
    Range("N" & i).Value = 15
    Range("O" & i).Value = 20

ElseIf Range("E" & i).Value = "Planning" Then
    Range("J" & i).Value = 35
    Range("K" & i).Value = 50
    Range("L" & i).Value = 25
    Range("M" & i).Value = 15
    Range("N" & i).Value = 15
    Range("O" & i).Value = 20`
```

You need to get rid of all the `And` statements in your `Then` clause.  This is an example.  You can change the rest.  You might want to look into the `Case Select` method as well.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try it and will let you know. Thanks sonmuch for your help! :-)

Comment: Hey @ValS [if you find this answer solved your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please consider marking it as the accepted. It helps both you and the person who helped you :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png